# mysql ensure only one access at a time

Tags: mysql

I'm connecting to a mysql-database by several threads in Java. Sometimes, the threads are reading and updating the same column of a database-table so that some **inconsistency** appears. 
In Java there is a `synchronized` keyword which limits the access to one ressource. **Are there any possible limitation for the mysql-database?** So that these inconsistencies do not occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use transactions with the appropiate isolation level.

Simplified example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...
COMMIT
```

[Mysql docs about transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)
 [Mysql docs about isolation levels](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html).

Comment: Transactions are only available on Innodb, for MyIsam he'll have to use Table locks: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/lock-tables.html

Comment: I'm already using stored procedures, do they don't they procide the same functionality? Furthermore, if I have 10 transactions or table locks, do they provide data consistency? The transactions/locks would be separately executed by different threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a version column, that way you can know if someone messed with your data while you work on it.

meaning: add a column named "updated" of type datetime, and whenever updating check that the updated you got is the same as the one on row in db, if they're not you know someone worked on your record.